# Move last couple of words to the front same column

Tags: mysql, plsql

I am trying to create a command that will take the last couple of words from a column and add it to the front (and removing a comma), for example:

```
Update:
Engineering and Applied Science (SEAS), The Fu Foundation School of


To:
The Fu Foundation School of Engineering and Applied Science (SEAS)
```

I have this so far

```
update ONLINE_GIFT_DIVISIONS
set test_newgiving_name = case
                    when DIVISION_TITLE LIKE '%, School of%' then
                     ''
                    when DIVISION_TITLE LIKE '%, Graduate School of%' then
                     ''
                    when DIVISION_TITLE LIKE '%, Mailman School of%' then
                     ''
                    when DIVISION_TITLE LIKE '%, The Fu Foundation School of%' then
                     ''
                  end
where division_title like '%, School of%'
where division_title like '%, Graduate School of%'
where division_title like '%, Mailman School of%'
where division_title like '%, The Fu Foundation School of%';
```

Comment: Have you tried **anything** for yourself?

Comment: Yes i have this so far: update ONLINE_GIFT_DIVISIONS
   set test_newgiving_name = case
                        when DIVISION_TITLE LIKE '%, School of%' then
                         ''
   when DIVISION_TITLE LIKE '%, Mailman School of%' then
                         ''
   when DIVISION_TITLE LIKE '%, The Fu Foundation School of%' then
                         ''
                      end
 where division_title like '%, School of%'
 where division_title like '%, Graduate School of%'
 where division_title like '%, Mailman School of%'
 where division_title like '%, The Fu Foundation School of%';

Comment: Does `plsql` really require 4 `where` clauses or would ONE `WHERE` and 3 `OR` be more syntactically correct?

Comment: I'm a farily new to SQL update queries. I'm not aware of anyway else to run an update query :)

Comment: If you are new to all this then [try giving the manual a try](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

Comment: last couple of words?what makes it to be the last couple of words?can you be more specific?what condition does it have to satisfy to be considered as the 'last couple of words'.

Comment: Good point brenners1302 I came across the following case "Social and Economic Research and Policy, Institute of (ISERP)" I will need to figure out how to remove the comma, take the "Institute of" part and move it to the front but also leave the "(ISERP)" at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this Oracle PL/SQL? In this case you could use regexp to swap the two parts (but not with the greatest perfs):

### with Oracle `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

you have 2 elements embraced with `()` that can be anything -> `.*`, split by a comma: this gives you a pattern like this: `(.*),(.*)`. First element is then addressed by `\1` and second by `\2` in the replace -> replacement string becomes then `\2 \1`.

```
SELECT 
  regexp_replace(str_var, '(.*),(.*)', '\2 \1'), str_var  FROM 
      (
           select 'Engineering and Applied Science (SEAS), The Fu Foundation School of' str_var from dual
union all  select 'ISIMA the best, Mailman School of'                                           from dual
union all  select 'another text, splitted with comma, but if there is another ? '               from dual
  ) ;
```

Using it to update your table:

```
update ONLINE_GIFT_DIVISIONS
  set test_newgiving_name = regexp_replace(DIVISION_TITLE, '(.*),(.*)' , '\2 \1')  
where division_title like '%, School of%'
   or division_title like '%, Graduate School of%'
   or division_title like '%, Mailman School of%'
   or division_title like '%, The Fu Foundation School of%';
```

Hope this is of any help.